# Run macro only if a cell contains a date

Tags: excel, vba

Is this possible? In my workbook I have a macro that creates a .txt file and emails it to a static box and is called by a command button. Is it possible to edit this macro to run only if cell B1 contains a date, and, if so, how?

Thank you.

```
Sub AnswerMe()
If IsDate(Range("B1").Value) Then
MsgBox "Plase enter a date in B1"
msg = "Email"
response = MsgBox(msg, vbYesNo)
If response = vbYes Then
CopyDistribute
Else
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You indicate below that the code above still doesn't work. Did you get it to work?

Comment: your problem is that you are wanting a date entered in B1. The `isDate` function will return true if B1 is a date. What you should change it to is `If isDate(Range("B1").Value) = false then`. Try that. Also make sure you are calling `CopyDistribute`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make it that when you click the command button it only runs the code if it is a date then encapsulate the code between `Sub commandbutton_click()` and `End Sub` with

```
If IsDate(Range("B1").Value) Then
    'Code required
End If
```

Otherwise if you want it to start whenever you open the sheet the following will work, just change my anecdote.

```
Private Sub worksheet_activate()

If IsDate(Range("B1").Value) Then
    MsgBox "Sure thing honey it's a date"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Was about to point out that Activate event is not advisable since that will trigger the macro to run everytime that particular sheet is selected. +1 still though.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. In my attempts to tweak this for my purpose I've come up with the code I've added in my first post. It does not work.

Comment: is `CopyDistribute` a function? You should try `Call CopyDistribute()` if that is the case but be sure to note that if you have written the function in for example Module1 then you will want to `Call Module1.CopyDistribute()`. Also is `AnswerMe()` the macro that is run when the commandbutton is clicked. What part does not work?